# How to filter rows through dtypes?

Tags: pandas

I have a column which has 500 line items in total. Out of those 34 are object and rest of them are integer. How do I filter that column to get only the object ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,'a','b',3]})

df.loc[[not isinstance(x,int) for x in df['col']],
       'col']
```

Output:

```
2    a
3    b
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: I can get columns on the basis on this but how do I further filter a column on the basis of dtypes of each element in the column ?

Comment: @Tanmayagrawal I misread your question. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
cond = df['col'].apply(type) != int
df.loc[cond]
```